# Property of the inverse of a symmetric matrix with dominant diagonal.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, symmetric-matrices

Let $M \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ be a symmetric matrix with positive entries and with dominant diagonal. This means that, for any $i$,
$$M_{i,i} > \sum_{j\neq i} M_{i,j}.$$
Thanks to Hadamard's lemma, we know that $M$ is invertible.

Is it true that we always have that
$$(M^{-1})_{i,i} > (M^{-1})_{i,j}$$
for any $i \neq j$?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What evidence do you have that suggests that this is true (besides obviously the 2D case )?

Comment: I could reduce a personal question to this "lemma" (assuming it's true) in the sense that it is equivalent to the result I want to prove. I have a strong confidence into this result.

Comment: I did not detail the context since it is quite long and the asked question is totally hidden on it. But shortly, I am proving results on solutions of convex optimization problems, more precisely the dependency of the solutions with some parameters, and a matrix with this property appears, for which I would be happy to prove the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The is true. Partition $M$ as
$$
\pmatrix{m_{11}&v^T\\ v&S}.
$$
Using [Schur complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M-matrix), we obtain
$$
N:=M^{-1}=\pmatrix{(m_{11}-v^TS^{-1}v)^{-1}&\ast\\
-(m_{11}-v^TS^{-1}v)^{-1}S^{-1}v&\ast}.
$$
As $M$ is a strictly diagonally dominant real symmetric matrix with a positive diagonal, it is positive definite. Therefore $n_{11}=(m_{11}-v^TS^{-1}v)^{-1}>0$. It follows that $n_{11}>n_{i1}$ for all $i\ne 1$ if and only if $-S^{-1}v<e$, i.e., if and only if $S^{-1}v+e>0$.

Denote by $D$ and $F$ the diagonal and off-diagonal parts of $S$  respectively, so that $S=D+F$. Since $M$ is entrywise positive and strictly diagonally dominant, $(I\pm D^{-1}F)^{-1}$ can be expanded as a Neumann series, $(D-F)^{-1}$ is entrywise positive, and $(D-F)e-v>0$. It follows that $e>(D-F)^{-1}v$ and
$$
\begin{aligned}
S^{-1}v+e
&=(D+F)^{-1}v+e\\
&>(D+F)^{-1}v+(D-F)^{-1}v\\
&=\left[(I+D^{-1}F)^{-1}+ (I-D^{-1}F)^{-1}\right]D^{-1}v\\
&=2\left[I+(D^{-1}F)^2+(D^{-1}F)^4+\ldots\right]D^{-1}v\\
&>0.
\end{aligned}
$$